# Is an adjective make uncountable noun countable?

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

I've mentioned in the previous [question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/305549/your-confusion-or-your-confusions/305577#305577) a few days ago that **advice** is an uncountable noun. I've seen when the noun is attached with an adjective beside it, there are some that have article **a** and some don't

A question taken from an English grammar app verifies my question, but since it's an app, I'm still not sure. Anyway, this is the question and there are only 3 options:

> My father gave me __ excellent advice.
>
> 1. a
> 2. the
> 3. an

The answer key is **an**. Why is it not **the** and why does it need an additional article when the verb **advice** is uncountable?

Comment: If this app tells you that "My father gave me **an** excellent advice" is correct, then throw this app in the trash.  The app was probably not written by a native English speaker.   *Advice* is not countable and you can't use the indefinite article with it.

Comment: What @stangdon said (avoid that app *and the website where you found it*). Having said that, there's nothing wrong with *My father gave me **the** excellent advice **that** I should delete the app and demand a refund from the supplier.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would tell you that it actually sounds strange to say

> My father gave me **an** excellent advice.

It is more natural (and idiomatic) to say any of the following:

> My father gave me excellent advice.

> My father gave me **some** excellent advice.

> My father gave me **a** [*piece of* excellent advice](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/thesaurus/a-piece-of-advice).

For the sake of argument, it is also possible to use "the".  To do so, there must be some context such that there is one "advice" being discussed.  One possible example:

> A: Wow, turning it around is a great idea!  How did you figure that out?
>
> B: My father gave me **the** excellent advice, and I took it!

Answer (score 3):

You are right that "advice" is uncountable, and the app question seems odd.

Many nouns can have both countable and uncountable senses. However "advice" is nearly always uncountable.

In the context in the question, you could either use no article "gave me excellent advice".  Or you could use a determiner "some excellent advice".  Or a quantifier "a piece of excellent advice" or perhaps "an excellent piece of advice".